# Pass search string in URL rather than use searchresults.php file

Tags: php, url

At present I'm trying to build a simple listing page of hotels that are returned from the Expedia EAN API. Just using a basic **`searchresults.php`** page with that has values like

```
foreach($hotels  as $key => $value) {  

$hotelId = $value['hotelId'];
etc...
```

And have a search form page that contains an input field for the search string and also two date pickers for arrival/departure date.

Bit of a newbie to PHP (getting hold of it pretty quickly), how do I display search results on a physical URL 
i.e.

```
localhost/mydomain/Hotel-Search?#&destination=London&startDate=15/01/2015&endDate=16/01/2015
```

Instead of

```
localhost/searchresults.php
```

So basically when I submit the form I want it to retrieve the values entered from the search form page and then create a URL based on the search string/arrival/departure dates as provided in the example above.

Comment: first you have to turn rewrite engine (if you want your URL be pretty;-), than after getting results via API make simple redirection to place your data into URL

Comment: Not fussed about it being a clean/pretty URL. Thing I don't want a redirect to occur as if you click the back button in the browser the user will see a "Resubmit" box. The form action="searchresults.php" is the culprit but I don't know enough to query the API from the search form page then pass the search string/dates in to the URL on the subsequent search results listing page

Comment: maybe you are looking for method GET in your form. should do the trick. `<form action="searchresults.php" method="get">`

Comment: Jesus, it's always the small things! Thanks, updated the functions and is now working fine.